# How do I get access to the <html> element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

IE displays a default scrollbar on the page, which appears even if the content is too short to require a scrollbar.

The typical way to remove this scrollbar (if not needed), is to add this to your CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in Javascript (without requiring that in my CSS), but I can't seem to find a way to get access to the `<html>` element.  I know I can access the `<body>` element with `document.body`, but that doesn't seem to be sufficient, I need the wrapping `<html>` element.

Any tips?

Comment: This is what CSS is for. This is not what Javascript is for. Why are you trying to do it in Javascript?

Comment: I disagree. (Not that that's what CSS for, but disagreeing that there aren't reasons why you'd need to do this in javascript.) The question is sound: ... how do you access the element? (styles and CSS aside.)

Comment: I wanted to this this conditionally (instead of applying it all the time).  If that were not the case, i would just do it in CSS.

Comment: Even if you want to do it conditionally, it's better to do with a CSS class than with Javascript access to the style properties. But even so if the condition is applied client-side, you'd obviously need access to the `<html>` element. To Funka, I never said the question is invalid, I asked for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `document.documentElement` property.

Comment: In IE, this element is only available in standards mode.

Answer (score 1):

I guess for completeness' sake, I'll add another way to access it:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
```

Obviously this is a little more verbose, but it's always going to work regardless of the structure or standards-mode of your document.

Answer (score 0):

You can also reach the HTML element with:

```
var html = document.body.parentNode;
alert(html.nodeName);
```